# How to look for a SQl Server row based on a paragraph - specifically, the words in the paragraph, not the exact paragraph

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, full-text-search

I want to use SQL Server 2005 Express to find the top five tuples related to a paragraph of text.  I know I can use Full Text Indexing and CONTAINSTABLE to find rows that contain an exact phrase, but how do I get it to return the closest matches to the words in a paragraph, not the exact paragraph itself.

So far the only way I can think of is to split the CONTAINSTABLE query, inserting ' or ' for every space character, generating a query along the lines of the following, but am concerned about performance (and stop words).

```
SELECT  id, FT.rank, description
FROM    SearchTable
    INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE (SearchTable, *, 
            '"This" OR "is" OR "my" OR "paragraph"') AS FT 
            ON SearchTable.id = FT.[key]
ORDER BY Rank DESC
```

I expect there's a standard solution to this problem - does anyone know what it is?

Comment: well i don't know of a better way to do it, but one problem with they way you're thinking of doing it is that you are including all the really frequent words such as is, and, my, etc.

Comment: yeah, that's what I meant by 'stop words'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the FREETEXT and FREETEXTTABLE which should do what you are trying to do?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879300.aspx

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what you want.  FREETEXT/FREETEXTTABLE automatically splits the search text into words, and the ranking is based on how well it matches - exact phrase ranks highest, then all words, etc.

Comment: Ahhh - so this is the difference between FREETEXTTABLE and CONTAINSTABLE!  Head-Slap moment :0)  Many thanks.